# Cannot connect to RDS Postgres using Golang Gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, amazon-rds, go-gorm

I got this error when trying to connect to my RDS Postgres Endpoint

> dial tcp 172.xx.xx.x:5432: i/o timeout panic: runtime error: invalid
>   memory address or nil pointer dereference [signal SIGSEGV:
>   segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x98 pc=0x1600d16]

Seems like there's some problem connecting to the endpoint

.Env file

```
DB_HOST=dbname.asdasddsa.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USER=username
DB_NAME=dbname
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

My database.go file

```
func InitDB() *gorm.DB {
    loadEnv() // For environment variables
    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable password=%s",
        os.Getenv("DB_HOST"),
        os.Getenv("DB_USER"),
        os.Getenv("DB_NAME"),
        os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
    )

    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return nil
    }
    fmt.Println("Connected to the Database")
    DB = db
    return DB
}
```

Do i need to configure anything in my RDS AWS? I followed this article

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-connect-postgresql-db/

and followed the exact steps for the configuration

Regards,

Comment: did you configure it as 'publicly accessible'?

Comment: @Praveen that's not necessary, they're connecting using private IP address. It's likely a security group issue.

Comment: Have you tried IP address in your db_host?

Comment: I've had a similar issue but fixed using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76899023/rds-while-connection-error-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host

Answer (score 0):

I am using this function to connect to my postgres database on RDS

```
package database

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    config "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

func Connect() (*gorm.DB, error) {
    return gorm.Open(
        "postgres",
        fmt.Sprintf(
            "host=%s port=%s user=%s dbname=%s password=%s",
            config.GetString("postgres.host"),
            config.GetString("postgres.port"),
            config.GetString("postgres.user"),
            config.GetString("postgres.dbname"),
            config.GetString("postgres.password"),              
        ),
    )
}
```

Please check if you have access to your RDS database before running this.
You can check if you have access to the database from AWS console -> RDS -> database ->  -> [scroll down] under Security group rules
You can see if you have added access to the security group to access your database from your network.

You can learn more about security groups here 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#VPCSecurityGroups